# JQUERY Add checked attribute to checkbox depending on Table column value `Status` (1 or 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've been googling really hard on this but putting the keywords checkbox and table together gives me results of "getting row values of checked row".

And I've landed to rare questions with the same concerns but it is all advanced (ajax, angularjs) I'm just a student-level programmer(basic jquery at most).

so I have this:
So what it does is it takes the values of the cell and puts it into textbox, no problem there but I want to take the value of `status` which is 1 (for active) and put it into a checkbox, if the value is 1 the checkbox will be checked, and if 0 it will not be checked.

I thank you all in advance, and please forgive the student-y coding, I'd appreciate any corrections though, although my understanding is limited, I'm continuously trying to widen my knowledge.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".buttonedit").click(function(){
  var Lastname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
  var Firstname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
  var Status = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
    $("#lname").val(Lastname);
    $("#fname").val(Firstname);
    
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="solid">
  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>lastnmae</td>
      <td>firstname</td>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>gates</td>
      <td>bill</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><button class="buttonedit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter lastname"id="lname"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter firstname"id="fname"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status">Active?<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing pretty well,
Just Add this line:

```
$('#status').attr('checked',Status=='1');
```

in your script.

Comment: You also need to set checked to `false` as well, in case you click a second time.

Comment: Ya, missed that

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/n5s721bv/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonedit").click(function(){
  var Lastname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
  var Firstname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
  var Status = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
        $("#lname").val(Lastname);
        $("#fname").val(Firstname);
        $('#status').prop('checked', parseInt(Status));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="solid">
  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>lastnmae</td>
      <td>firstname</td>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>gates</td>
      <td>bill</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><button class="buttonedit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test11</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><button class="buttonedit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test9</td>
      <td>bill</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><button class="buttonedit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter lastname"id="lname"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter firstname"id="fname"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status">Active?<br>
</form>
```

Since **Status** variable contains the data but it's typeof is **string** so I'm changing it to integer using **parseInt** as checkbox checked / unchecked.

Comment: Note that `checked` is a boolean, so your code here is *explicitly* parsing the string to an int, then *implicitly* parsing it again to a boolean. You may as well not bother with the int step, and go straight to a boolean.

Comment: It works in JSFiddle but when I implemented it in my code it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `prop()` to set the checked state of the checkbox. To make it work you need to set the value as a boolean. To achieve that you can use the result of `Status == '1'`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttonedit").click(function() {
    var Lastname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var Firstname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var Status = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
    
    $("#lname").val(Lastname);
    $("#fname").val(Firstname);
    $('#status').prop('checked', Status == '1'); // note this line
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="solid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>lastnmae</td>
      <td>firstname</td>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>gates</td>
      <td>bill</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><button class="buttonedit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ballmer</td>
      <td>steve</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><button class="buttonedit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter lastname" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter firstname" id="fname"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status">Active?<br>
</form>
```